# Archaic Form Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I have a form and unfortunately built it without the help of external libraries (which I am now cursing myself for not including). So my form validation isn't just form.validate() or something similar, it's going to have to be an archaic javascript method (time constraints means I cannot implement external libraries because it'd involve rebuilding the form).

All I want is to check all the fields have been filled in - no email validation or post-code validation etc.

I tried a simple version:

```
if((document.getElementById("fieldA").value != "") || (document.getElementById("fieldB").value != "")){
   alert("form okay");
}else{
   alert("form not okay");
}
```

but this doesn't work. The alternative to this would be to nest 45 if statements detecting each field individually but this is tedious and unfeasible.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't specific enough.  If something is failing, please describe how it fails and give any error message you have.

Comment: Just change || to && and it should work. As it stands you are accepting the form if only one field is filled in.

Comment: In reply to your removed comment. If this code is executed at least one of the alerts will be called. If neither alert is called there must be another problem elsewhere preventing this from executing

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than 'this doesn't work'? How doesn't it work? Do you get nothing? Do you get the wrong alert? Also helpful to include more of your code, such as the function that contains that IF statement (I hope/assume it's a function), and the form element that calls the function.

Comment: @Noel Walters - I retested the code, I always got the form not okay alert - hence why i deleted the comment, because it'd throw you off the scent. I guess it's my logic, I was in the wrong place with this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can loop trough elements in the form with

```
document.forms[0].elements
```

like

```
 var d = document.forms[0].elements
 var l = d.length;
 for(var i = 0; i < l; i ++) {
     var element = d[i];
     var type = element.type;
     var value = element.value;
     var class = element.className;
 }
```

dropdown:

```
document.forms[0].select.value
```

radiobuttons:

```
for (i=0;i<document.forms[0].radios.length;i++) {
    if (document.forms[0].radios[i].checked) {
        var value = document.forms[0].radios[i].value;
    }
}
```

[thanks to external libraries we don't need that to do ourselves these days](http://jquery.com/);)

Comment: this helped a lot! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

Your boolean logic is wrong - you want AND (`&&`) not OR (`||`) if you want to make *all* the fields required.  As it stands, the validation only checks to see if *one* field has been filled in.

Comment: my head logic read that as "if any of the fields are empty" which is what I want

Answer (score 2):

I think that Caspar's answer is excellent.  As an addition to it, what we have on old forms is a function to get elements by class name (not written by us):

```
function getElementsByClassName(className, tag, elm){
    var testClass = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)");
    var tag = tag || "*";
    var elm = elm || document;
    var elements = (tag == "*" && elm.all)? elm.all : elm.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var returnElements = [];
    var current;
    var length = elements.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
            current = elements[i];
            if(testClass.test(current.className)){
                    returnElements.push(current);
            }
    }
    return returnElements;
}
```

Then we put a class="validate" on each form element that needs validating and have this function run on form submit (where getFormElementValue is a function that handles the various different form elements as in Caspar's answer):

```
function validate(){
    var elementArray = ( getElementsByClassName('validate') ) ;
    for ( i=0; i<elementArray.length;  i++){
        if( getFormElementValue( elementArray[i] ) == '' ){
            alert( 'Form not OK' );
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this is that you can easily define which elements are compulsory and which are not without resorting to a list of names/IDs.